# I can build the project on the windows and mac.But it report error when I build on the ubuntu.The versions of node and npm are same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu, jenkins, build

I build the react project successful on the windows and mac.But it report error when I build on the ubuntu.The versions of node and npm are same.
I hava install the package.When I run 'npm run build' it report some errors.

The node version is v12.20.2.The npm version is 6.14.4.The yarn version is 1.22.5.The react version  is "react": "^16.11.0"

The log are:

```
root@HON-AI:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web# yarn run build
yarn run v1.22.5
$ node changeFileNames && node copyThemeFile &&  cross-env UMI_ENV=build umi build
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell-combined/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell-combined/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell-combined-all/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell-combined-all/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell-compact/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell-compact/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell-compact-dark/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell-compact-dark/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell-compact-combined/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell-compact-combined/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell-dark/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/honeywell-dark/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell-combined/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell-combined/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell-combined-all/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell-combined-all/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell-compact/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell-compact/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell-compact-combined/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell-compact-combined/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell-compact-dark/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell-compact-dark/theme.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell-dark/theme.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/datatable/honeywell-dark/theme.less
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
theme.cssreplace successful!
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/node_modules/rc-slider/assets/index.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/node_modules/rc-slider/assets/index.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/node_modules/rc-slider/dist/rc-slider.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/node_modules/rc-slider/dist/rc-slider.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/node_modules/rc-slider/dist/rc-slider.css.map
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/node_modules/rc-slider/dist/rc-slider.less.map
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/node_modules/rc-slider/dist/rc-slider.min.css
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/node_modules/rc-slider/dist/rc-slider.min.less
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/node_modules/rc-slider/dist/rc-slider.min.css.map
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@scuf/common/node_modules/rc-slider/dist/rc-slider.min.less.map
index.cssreplace successful!
rc-slider.cssreplace successful!
rc-slider.css.mapreplace successful!
rc-slider.min.cssreplace successful!
rc-slider.min.css.mapreplace successful!

✖ Webpack
  Compiled with some errors in 1.90m

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 12 errors                                                                                                                                                                                              10:24:33 AM

These dependencies were not found:

* /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/TrailUser/register in ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
* /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/User/SetPwd in ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
* @/pages/Home/Widgets/Widgets in ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
* @/pages/Home/Widgets/tiles/weather/weatherUtil in ./src/models/weather.ts
* React in ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/ApplyTemplate/ApplyTemplate.tsx, ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/ChangeDeviceStatus/ChangeDeviceStatus.tsx and 4 others

To install them, you can run: npm install --save /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/TrailUser/register /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/User/SetPwd @/pages/Home/Widgets/Widgets @/pages/Home/Widgets/tiles/weather/weatherUtil React


These relative modules were not found:

* ./basicAsssetInfo.less?modules in ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Equipment/components/BasicAsssetInfo/BasicAsssetInfo.tsx
* ./utils/jsonUtil in ./src/framework/src/index.ts
Child
    
    ERROR in ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Equipment/components/BasicAsssetInfo/BasicAsssetInfo.tsx
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './basicAsssetInfo.less?modules' in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/Home/Equipment/Equipment/components/BasicAsssetInfo'
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Equipment/components/BasicAsssetInfo/BasicAsssetInfo.tsx 11:0-52 248:19-25 250:19-25 252:19-25 254:19-25 258:19-25 266:19-25 268:19-25 279:19-25 281:19-25 284:19-25 292:19-25 294:19-25 304:19-25 306:19-25 308:19-25 311:19-25 319:19-25 321:19-25 324:19-25 332:19-25 334:19-25
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Equipment/DetailAsset/DetailAsset.tsx
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/EQManagement.tsx
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
     @ multi ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
    
    ERROR in ./src/framework/src/index.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './utils/jsonUtil' in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/framework/src'
     @ ./src/framework/src/index.ts 16:0-44 20:0-25:16
     @ ./src/models/jobFunction.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/plugin-dva/dva.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/plugin-dva/exports.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/umiExports.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/plugin-initial-state/Provider.tsx
     @ ./src/.umi-production/plugin-initial-state/runtime.tsx
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/pluginRegister.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
     @ multi ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
    
    ERROR in ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/TrailUser/register' in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/.umi-production/core'
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts 484:19-486:81
     @ ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
     @ multi ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
    
    ERROR in ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/User/SetPwd' in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/.umi-production/core'
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts 474:19-476:74
     @ ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
     @ multi ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
    
    ERROR in ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/pages/Home/Widgets/Widgets' in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/.umi-production/core'
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts 51:19-53:43
     @ ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
     @ multi ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
    
    ERROR in ./src/models/weather.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/pages/Home/Widgets/tiles/weather/weatherUtil' in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/models'
     @ ./src/models/weather.ts 4:0-82 236:12-28
     @ ./src/.umi-production/plugin-dva/dva.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/plugin-dva/exports.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/umiExports.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/plugin-initial-state/Provider.tsx
     @ ./src/.umi-production/plugin-initial-state/runtime.tsx
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/pluginRegister.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
     @ multi ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
    
    ERROR in ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/ApplyTemplate/ApplyTemplate.tsx
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'React' in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/ApplyTemplate'
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/ApplyTemplate/ApplyTemplate.tsx 5:0-31 61:37-56 61:57-71 61:92-111 63:23-42 69:26-45 86:2-21
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Docks/DockDetail/DockSettings/DockSettings.tsx
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Docks/DockDetail/DockDetail.tsx
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
     @ multi ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
    
    ERROR in ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/ChangeDeviceStatus/ChangeDeviceStatus.tsx
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'React' in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/ChangeDeviceStatus'
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/ChangeDeviceStatus/ChangeDeviceStatus.tsx 5:0-31 66:37-56 66:57-71 66:92-111 68:23-42 74:26-45 91:2-21
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Docks/DockList.tsx
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
     @ multi ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
    
    ERROR in ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/SetParams/SetParams.tsx
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'React' in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/SetParams'
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/SetParams/SetParams.tsx 9:0-31 133:36-55 144:35-54 150:38-57 152:22-41 155:40-59 157:22-41 159:23-42 167:30-49 167:50-64 168:26-45 188:2-21
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Docks/DockList.tsx
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
     @ multi ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
    
    ERROR in ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/SetPassword/SetPassword.tsx
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'React' in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/SetPassword'
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Components/SetPassword/SetPassword.tsx 5:0-31 52:26-45 52:76-95 54:22-41 54:83-102 54:145-164 86:26-45 106:2-21
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Equipment/Docks/DockList.tsx
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
     @ multi ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
    
    ERROR in ./src/pages/Home/Organization/Sites/Site/Gateway/Components/ManuallyAssignDock/ManuallyAssignDock.tsx
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'React' in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/Home/Organization/Sites/Site/Gateway/Components/ManuallyAssignDock'
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Organization/Sites/Site/Gateway/Components/ManuallyAssignDock/ManuallyAssignDock.tsx 9:0-31 276:26-45 278:22-41 280:22-41 282:22-41 284:23-42 294:24-43 296:22-41 298:22-41 300:22-41 307:23-42 314:23-42 321:24-43 326:24-43 328:22-41 328:81-100 335:25-44 337:22-41 348:25-44 350:22-41 363:26-45 375:22-41 375:75-94 380:24-43 380:227-246 380:390-409 382:22-41 389:23-42 444:30-49 444:50-64 445:26-45 467:2-21
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Organization/Sites/Site/Gateway/Info/GatewayInfo.tsx
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
     @ multi ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
    
    ERROR in ./src/pages/Home/Schedule/Components/DeleteActivities/DeleteActivities.tsx
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'React' in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/Home/Schedule/Components/DeleteActivities'
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Schedule/Components/DeleteActivities/DeleteActivities.tsx 5:0-31 27:26-45 49:26-45 65:2-21
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Schedule/ScheduleActivities.tsx
     @ ./src/pages/Home/Schedule/Schedule.tsx
     @ ./src/.umi-production/core/routes.ts
     @ ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
     @ multi ./src/.umi-production/umi.ts
null
build failed
Error: build failed
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/@umijs/bundler-webpack/lib/index.js:138:27
    at finalCallback (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:254:12)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:277:6
    at done (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2931:13)
    at runCompilers (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:181:48)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:188:7
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:270:7
    at finalCallback (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:257:39)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:273:13
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:40:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at onCompiled (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:271:21)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:681:15
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:678:31
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The package.json are:

```
{
    "name": "ssrtm",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Safety Suite Realtime Monitor",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "presite": "node changeFileNames && node copyThemeFile && node ./scripts/generateMock.js && cd functions && npm install",
        "start": "node changeFileNames && node copyThemeFile && cross-env UMI_ENV=debug umi dev",
        "start:no-mock": "node changeFileNames && node copyThemeFile && cross-env UMI_ENV=debug MOCK=none umi dev",
        "build": "node changeFileNames && node copyThemeFile &&  cross-env UMI_ENV=build umi build",
        "prod": "node changeFileNames && node copyThemeFile &&  cross-env UMI_ENV=prod umi build",
        "onpremiss": "node changeFileNames && node copyThemeFile &&  cross-env UMI_ENV=prem umi build",
        "onpremissPlant": "node changeFileNames && node copyThemeFile &&  cross-env UMI_ENV=premPlant umi build",
        "onpremissResponder": "node changeFileNames && node copyThemeFile &&  cross-env UMI_ENV=premResponder umi build",
        "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=1 umi build",
        "test": "umi test",
        "test:component": "umi test ./src/components",
        "test:all": "node ./tests/run-tests.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-google-maps/api": "^1.7.7",
        "@scuf/common": "^1.6.10",
        "@scuf/datatable": "1.6.6",
        "@scuf/localization": "1.5.2",
        "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
        "base64-js": "^1.3.1",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
        "dva": "^2.4.1",
        "echarts": "4.0.4",
        "echarts-for-react": "2.0.16",
        "gcoord": "^0.2.3",
        "hash.js": "^1.1.5",
        "js-base64": "^3.4.5",
        "lodash": "^4.17.10",
        "lodash.isequal": "^4.0.0",
        "memoize-one": "^5.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "numeral": "^2.0.6",
        "path-to-regexp": "^2.4.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "puppeteer": "^1.10.0",
        "qs": "^6.6.0",
        "rc-slider": "^9.7.1",
        "rc-switch": "^3.2.2",
        "react": "^16.11.0",
        "react-datepicker": "^2.9.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
        "react-draggable": "^4.0.3",
        "react-resizable": "1.9.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "typescript": "^3.5.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
        "@types/react": "^16.7.7",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.10",
        "@umijs/preset-react": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1.1",
        "cross-port-killer": "^1.0.1",
        "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
        "eslint": "^5.4.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-compat": "^2.6.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-markdown": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
        "husky": "^1.2.0",
        "jest-puppeteer": "^4.2.0",
        "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
        "merge-umi-mock-data": "^0.0.3",
        "mockjs": "^1.0.1-beta3",
        "postcss-plugin-px2rem": "^0.8.1",
        "prettier": "^2.1.2",
        "pro-download": "^1.0.1",
        "slash2": "^2.0.0",
        "stylelint": "^9.8.0",
        "stylelint-config-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.0.0",
        "tslint": "^5.10.0",
        "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.10.0",
        "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
        "umi": "3.2.28",
        "umi-plugin-ga": "^1.1.3",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
    },
    "optionalDependencies": {
        "puppeteer": "^1.10.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=8.0.0"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not ie <= 10"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try to install the dependencies that the error message is telling you to?

Comment: I did it.But it did not fail.
The log are:
root@HON-AI:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web# npm install --save /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/TrailUser/register /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RTM-QA-web/src/pages/User/SetPwd @/pages/Home/Widgets/Widgets @/pages/Home/Widgets/tiles/weather/weatherUtil React
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "src/pages/TrailUser/register" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-05-14T03_04_58_847Z-debug.log